# Exclude space from allowed input when entering float number

Tags: python, validation, input

I've written a validation function that looks like this:

```
    def validateFloat(self, text): 
    if (text == ''):
        return True
    try:
        float(text)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

But I can still enter spaces after I enter a digit. I want to make it so that it doesn't allow spaces, only dots and digits. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you want to disallow that? The question is not clear. Can you add examples for what exactly you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to catch spaces

```
def validateFloat(self, text): 
  if (text == ''):
    return True
  elif ' ' in text:
    return False
  try:
    float(text)
    return True
  except ValueError:
    return False
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use

```
x=isinstance(text,float)
```

if text variable is float, this will return true.

To remove space from text use strip function as mentioned below.

```
text.strip()
```

If you want to check whitespace in text. Use below

```
if ' ' in text:
```